# Cocoa application with SwiftPM

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift-package-manager

My general goal is to create an app, that grabs all data from the postgreSQL database. Firstly, I connected C API libpq to connect my database. Then, I found a [nice wrapper around libpq](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-PostgreSQL) to make my life easier, thanks to Perfect. To install this wrapper, I need to create Package.swift, add a dependency and regenerate my xcodeproj with `swift package generate-xcodeproj`.

But when I do that, the whole structure of my project is being rebuilt and, as a result, when I run the project, a simulator doesn't start and I lose understanding on what's happening and build usually fails.

[New project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3dMt.png)

It would've been nice if somebody explained to me, what happens when I generate a project after adding Package.swift file and how to keep everything working with new packages being added.

Answer (score 0):

> ... when I run the project, a simulator doesn't start and I lose understanding on what's happening and build usually fails.l

I suppose you already have the libpq added and working. If this is an iOS project, try just adding the PostgresSQL.swift instead of using the package.

Comment: [Postgresapp web-site](http://postgresapp.com) says, that for iOS I need to build libpq myself, that's why I decided to create macOS project, because there I can use provided libpq. With clean libpq it all works fine, but I just wanted to use Perfect wrapper to make my code more readable and perform more complex tasks easier. And connecting this wrapper package through SPM appeared to be a problem to me